# JQuery does not see the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Part of html-code page:

```
<td class="calendar-footer-cell" style="min-width: 135px; max-width: 135px;">
    <table id="in_out_time" style="cursor: pointer; color:#BBBBBB; font-family: cbuc-icons Regular, cbuc-icons;">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="field-label">
                <td id="timeIdName" style="width: 100px; white-space: nowrap; padding-right: 5px; height: 20px">09:52</td>
                <td class="table_td_all_time" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">04:08</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="field-label">
                <td class="table_time_in_out" style="width: 100px; height: 20px;">09:52</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
#timeIdName {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

In the block "timeIdName" in the css-settings you want to change "white-space" to "pre".

If you are using:

```
$('#timeIdName').css("white-space", "pre");
```

nothing changes.

Can you please tell how to change the setting?

Comment: That should work. Is your code in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: You have a typo - missing closing quote in the selector.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan for the formatting. That's a thankless task.

Answer (score 1):

Correcting your typo and using documet ready, it should work:

```
$(function(){
    $('#timeIdName').css("white-space", "pre");
});
```

We should select any element only after the document ready event is triggered. The above is a shorthand of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#timeIdName').css("white-space", "pre");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wirte following code in document ready event, it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#timeIdName").css("white-space", "pre");
});
```

Comment: Downvoter please commment

Comment: It wasn't me, but I guess it's because you still have an error with the quotes in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check your code, you are not using quotes properly...

```
$('#timeIdName').css("white-space", "pre");
```

Note the closing single quote in the selector.